# signInAnonymously:FAILURE com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: despite Anonymous Sign in enabled

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

Despite I have enabled in my Firebase project anonymous sign in, my mobile (Android) app is not able to authenticate and I'm getting this error (on emulator and on physical device too).

> signInAnonymously:FAILURE
> com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This operation is restricted to administrators only.

My Firebase config:

[image]

My code:

```
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
...
 // Sign in anonymously. Authentication is required to read or write from Firebase Storage.
    mAuth
        .signInAnonymously()
        .addOnSuccessListener(
            mActivity,
            authResult -> {
              Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:SUCCESS");
              try {
                upload();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "upload:FAILURE", e);
              }
            })
        .addOnFailureListener(
            mActivity,
            exception -> {
              Log.e(TAG, "signInAnonymously:FAILURE", exception);
            });
  }
```

Dependencies:

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.0'
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2"
```

Does anybody had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, I updated packages to this:

```
+    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.2')
+    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
+    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'

...  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:18.0.2" //not updated
```

Make the Firebase storage rules look like this(disclaimer: for my debug version, production I suppose will be more strict):

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
​
```

And it started to work. But honestly not sure why  ¯\*(ツ)*/¯.

Comment: The Firebase [BoM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/learn-more#bom) ensures that only compatible versions of Firebase libraries are used. Maybe you had an incompatibility there or the BoM defines newer versions that fixed something?